# Regular Expression for the url

Tags: jquery

I am using the regular expression for the url `/\b(http|https)?(:\/\/)?(\S*)\.(\w{1,45})/ig`

But it is not validating, if the url is bigger. It is working upto half of the extend. If I am trying another regular expression after the url with space any words it is taking as a complete url with word. Can you please help me?

Comment: Can you provide some example data?

Comment: `^https?://` if you want to validate if the url begins with http or https.

Comment: this has nothing to do with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

if you want to extract the urls from a blob of text you can use the following regexp:

```
/
  http   // Match literal http
  s?     // Match 's' zero or one time
  :\/\/  // Match literal ://
  [^\s]+ // Match everything but spaces, tabs & newlines one or more times
/g
```

This will also match: `https://localhost` and `https://a`

```
var str = 'text here https://example.com/john.doe some more text and http://another.link.example.com/with?query=string';
str.match(/https?:\/\/[^\s]+/g) // ["https://example.com/john.doe", "http://another.link.example.com/with?query=string"]
```